# What is the name of the view of 'pulling up the ladder of Judeo-Christian morality'?

Tags: terminology, philosophy-of-religion

I overheard a friend say:

> We have progressed as a society to the point where the Judeo-Christian morality that once benefited us now holds us back. We have to pull up the ladder of XXX.

(I didn't hear what the XXX was - but apparently this has a name).

My question is: **What is the name of the viewpoint of 'pulling up the ladder of Judeo-Christian morality'?**

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. It was a literary reference to a ladder with a particular name

Comment: surely this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wittgenstein's_ladder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Wittgenstein's ladder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wittgenstein's_ladder) may be the ladder you need.  It's a process, described in the *Tractatus Logico-Philosophicus*, where each step prepares you to understand the next step, but should be discarded after you've gotten past that point.  It's similar to Plato's idea of the "noble lie," a deliberate falsehood meant to move you closer to a deeper truth, but with the explicit addition that the lie is only a step on the way.

If so, then your friend is saying that Judeo-Christian morality has gotten us somewhere, if not directly to the dissolution of itself, then perhaps to a material society where it's no longer needed.

Whether or not your friend means this I don't know.

Comment: Good work, @Mathemetician.  I edited in some explanation based on the Wiki article to flesh the answer out a little more.